# Inequality for probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Problem 3.4.2 in Rohatgi's **An introduction to probability and statistics** asks:

Given a random variable whose moment generating function exists, show that

$$P(mX \gt n^2 + \log(M(t)))< e^{-n^2}$$
for $m>0$, and any $s$.

Given that the problem appears in the same chapter as the Chebyshev inequality, I believe that it might be useful, but I am not sure how to start. Any hints on how to get the problem started?

Comment: I assume $X$ is the random variable and $M(t)$ is its moment generating function.  What is $m$?

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more precise, I've updated the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(mX>n^2+ln(M(t)))=P(e^{mX}>e^{n^2}M(t))\leq \frac{E[e^{mX}]}{E[e^{tX}]}e^{-n^2}\leq e^{-n^2}$, if $t\geq m$. (using Markov's inequality)